# How to add two icons to swing AbstractAction

Tags: java, swing, icons

My requirement is to add two icons to abstract action
Example: icon + action name + icon
AbstractAction has a super constructor to add only one icon

Comment: Do you have components that are capable of managing this?  By default, none of the Swing components can use more the one image at a time

Comment: @MadProgrammer nop, is there a way i can set a custom component to a menu

Comment: Not really, menus are a complete pain in the ... back. The problem is, even though you pass a `JMenuItem` to the `JMenu`, the `JMenu` does it's it own layout which is all tied into the look and feel delegate

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this by setting the action label as HTML